# Send a variable to other page (Send a message)

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

Assuming I have a registration and login page done, is there any way to send a variable from registration to login?

**My goal is to alert the user that the account has been created.** And it should look like this:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaFyT.png)

Comment: Yes, there are multiple ways, like: using a URL parameter, using a session, using a cookie. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I tried to search something like a Global Variable in php using "GET"

Comment: A global variable won't survive changing the page

Comment: A Cookie maybe?

Comment: Session value would probably be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably wanna use a session for this

Script for registration:

```
//Start session, you need to do this to use session variables
    session_start();
//Make the session variable
    $_SESSION['message']="Account has been created";
```

Login page:

```
    <?php
                session_start();
//Checks if the variable is declared, makes sure you don't get a warning for missing variable
                if (isset($_SESSION['message'])) {
//You can add whatever CSS class you want to this with "<div class='{Class name}'>". $_SESSION['message'] ."</div>"
                    echo $_SESSION['message'];
                }
//Unset the variable, this makes sure you don't get the message again when you reload, if you're not using sessions anymore session_destroy(); is even better
                unset($_SESSION['message']);
```

Comment: Thank you so much you saved me!

Comment: @rrenildopereiraa no problem, just noticed a little issue in my comment about how to add a css class. edited my answer

Could you also mark my answer as correct incase someone stumbles upon this post

Comment: hmm, i see... i'm new here so idk how to mark this as right